# Connect to joomla DB with JPATH_BASE and JFactory::getDBO

Tags: php, joomla, require-once

I have a joomla website and I am creating a photo gallery with a .php calling the pictures with a query1 SELECT (this php runs out of joomla but call the pictures from the joomla DB)

When the gallery.php is at the root of my website, it's working fine. But when I want to insert it in a folder then I get this error :

```
Warning: require_once(/homez.420/xxxxx/www/gallery/includes/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homez.420/xxxxx/www/gallery/gallery.php on line 30

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/homez.420/xxxxx/www/gallery/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /homez.420/xxxxx/www/gallery/gallery.php on line 30
```

I am still new to php and I can't get a way to find how to make those two lines jump out of the gallery folder so that it call this document instead : /homez.420/xxxxx/**www/includes**/defines.php

```
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

Here is the full code

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );  //this is line 30 : where the glitch is 
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You need to change this line to that it points to the correct directory: `define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );` .... also, you don't need to use `$db1` and `$db2`, just define it once like so: `$db = JFactory::getDbo();`

Comment: Thanks Lodder for your reply ! I am sorry for the $db1 and $db2, I did change it to $db = JFactory::getDbo();. I do understand what you mean by "You need to change this line to that it points to the correct directory" but I don't know how to do it. Should I do something like : `define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(/homez.420/xxxxx/www/) );`? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You gallery script is currently in the following folder `homez.420/xxxxx/www/gallery`, but where is the root of your Joomla site? Something like this >> `homez.420/xxxxx/www/joomla`? Once I know the root of your Joomla site, I can give you a specific answer for you code

Comment: it's  /homez.420/xxxxx/www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple : 
replace line 30 :

```
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
```

by website root path:

```
define('JPATH_BASE', '/homez.420/xxxxxxx/www');
```